# Laravel 7 boilerplate substitute of grafite/scaffold

Tags: php, html, laravel-7, boilerplate, laravel-cashier

Hello I updated laravel to version 7 with cashier 12. Till now the system used [grafite/builder](https://packagist.org/packages/grafite/builder) as u can see on the page, the package is abandoned and need to use [grafiteinc/scaffold](https://github.com/grafiteinc/scaffold). I can not install this package, because needs cashier 10, I have cashier 12 and I can not downgrade to 10, because I need to use multiplan subscription methods. So my question is, do you know some other boilerplate packages that match grafite/builder or scaffold and can use them with cashier 12 and laravel 7, because whole system use tags from them and I need to rewrite the views if can not find a new package. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `composer.json` from grafiteinc/scaffold says `"laravel/cashier": "^12.0",`

Comment: Thanks, but I realized that scaffold is not gonna help me to solve my issues. I will write forms in pure html